# Work Performer Exception: org.apache.soap.transport.SOAPTransport while executing ComponentStep in ProcessConfiguration of IBM FileNet

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-process-engine

While running component Step in ProcessConfiguration of workflows, facing below issue. This component includes web service calls. Added soap.jar file in the component but issue remains the same.

```
Work Performer Exception: org.apache.soap.transport.SOAPTransport 

When verified in PCCE logs, I find as below.

CMDp.MAS678A PEPrimary2 [Error] CMExecute[12917].MASMEDOC01.XSHDC510_DS_30.AdapterOperations.Y988309 [UKE_IndexingSME:D5C52E6172F0284385411683A8496EAB:sub_local_ExecuteForAttachment:adaptorCall] FAILED.; Exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.soap.transport.SOAPTransport 
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434) 
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:240) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:702) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:681) 
        at com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:133) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:664) 
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62) 
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58) 
        at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:617) 
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:664)
```

Issue : Work Performer Exception: org.apache.soap.transport.SOAPTransport

Can someone help the reason for this issue??

Answer (score -1):

try this

1. add the supporting jar as a content element within the code module
2. If 1 doesn't work, add the supporting jar to CPE Websphere library and restart the websphere

Comment: someone downvoted this answer. Would you care to give a reason?